# What are the State-of-the-Art open source alternatives to Stable Diffusion for Text-to-Image generation?

Tags: stable-diffusion, text-to-image

I'm currently working on a project involving text-to-image generation, and I've been using the [Stable Diffusion](https://github.com/Stability-AI/stablediffusion) model. While this model has been performing well, I'm interested in exploring other state-of-the-art open source alternatives to diversify my approach and **compare results**.

I'm particularly interested in models that have demonstrated strong performance in recent research and have an active community of developers. Ideally, these models should be relatively easy to use and have good documentation.

Could anyone recommend some alternatives to Stable Diffusion for text-to-image generation?

Comment: We are currently [in process of determining whether asking for recommendation is going to be on-topic or not](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158/are-questions-asking-for-recommendation-on-topic-in-such-case-what-are-our-guid).

Answer (score 3):

*Papers with Code* maintains [leaderboards across various text-to-image benchmarks](https://paperswithcode.com/task/text-to-image-generation), using metrics reported in papers. For example, on COCO:

[image: Image of the leaderboards]

Entries with the Github icon have code available, but note that some of these may be unofficial implementations or not yet have model weights available.

In this case the top result with code and weights available is [U-ViT-S/2-Deep](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/all-are-worth-words-a-vit-backbone-for-score). Appears relatively easy to get started with, including [a Colab notebook demo](https://colab.research.google.com/github/baofff/U-ViT/blob/main/UViT_ImageNet_demo.ipynb) (class-conditioned).

Currently it's unlikely to find anything with support to the level of Stable Diffusion (choice of frontends, text-conditioned training on web data, etc.), but this would be one place to watch for emerging research.